# Pressure inside a soap bubble made in a vacuum

Tags: classical-mechanics, pressure, fluid-statics

A question I came across:
A soap bubble is made in vacuum by blowing an ideal diatomic gas in it. Assume the heat capacity of the soap film is much greater than that of the gas in the bubble. What will be the molar heat capacity of the gas in the bubble?

The correct answer is given as $4R$ (R being the ideal gas constant), and I was able to reach this answer using the ideal gas equation to find $dV$, substituting into the first law of thermodynamics and using the fact that $C_v$ for a diatomic gas is $5R/2$.

However, to reach this answer I had to take the pressure inside the bubble as $8\sigma/r$ ($\sigma$ being the surface tension of the soap solution) instead of $4\sigma/r$ which is what I would usually take for the excess pressure inside a soap bubble, and since it is in vacuum I can take as the absolute pressure inside the bubble.

Is there a reason for this which I'm missing, or an error in the question/answer?

Comment: I'm willing to bet your missing factor of two is either because this is a full sphere and you're used to hemispheres, or because soap bubbles have two layers and you're used to a one-layer interface.

Comment: @electronpusher the excess pressure inside a one layer (full sphere) bubble is $2\sigma/r$ and so for a two layer bubble it would be $4\sigma/r$. I double checked just now, so I don't think this is the source of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say you have blown the air bubble to $V$ volume, $P$ Pressuse, $T$ temperature and with $n$ moles of that diatomic gas in it. Also the surface tension of the bubble be $\sigma$

Now, To calculate the molar specific heat i.e $C$, Let's say you gave some heat to the bubble i.e $Q$, due to which there will be some change in pressure, volume and temperature let's say $dP, dV, dT$ respectively and also the number of moles $(n)$ will be constant

As you stated by First Law of Thermodynamics,
$$ Q = dU + W $$
where all the terms have their usual meaning
$$ Q = nCdT$$
$$ dU = nC_v dT$$
Work can be calculated by two ways,
$$ W = PdV$$
$$or$$
$$ W = 2\sigma dA$$
$$W = 2\sigma\times  8\pi r dr$$
where $dA$ is elemental change in surface area

I am going with second you can verify the result for first also
$$nCdT = 2\sigma \times 8\pi rdr + nC_v dT $$
$$C = \mathrm{\frac{2\sigma\ \times 8\pi rdr}{n dT}} + C_v \qquad(1)$$

From ideal gas equation,
$$ P V = nR T$$
differentiating,
$$PdV + VdP = nRdT$$
$$ndT = \mathrm{\frac{PdV+VdP}{R}} $$

So equation (1) becomes,
$$C = \mathrm{\frac{2\sigma\ \times 8\pi rdr\times R}{PdV+VdP}} + C_v$$
$$P = \mathrm{\frac{4\sigma}{r}},V=\mathrm{\frac{4}{3}}\pi r^3, C_v = 5R/2$$
differentiate and substitute you will get the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Why did you take the work to be $2 \sigma dA$? I assume it is because the soap bubble has two layers, but then you took the area for both the layers as well? Could you explain why you took it twice?

Comment: $dA$ is the change in area of the bubble. Both layer will have change in area as $dA$ so net work done will be work done in expanding one layer + work done in expanding other layer which is $\sigma \times dA+\sigma \times dA = 2 \sigma dA$

Comment: @HridaiKhurana If you are confused in $dA$, Let's say you have a bubble with radius $r$, it expanded to radius $r+dr$.So,$dA=4\pi {(r+dr)}^2 - 4 \pi r^2$,$\Rightarrow dA=4\pi (r^2 +2rdr+{dr}^2) - 4\pi r^2$,${dr}^2$ will be very small so neglect it and you will have your result

Comment: Yes, I was confused in $dA$ but its clear now, thanks